# Implementing Twitter's Search API in Apache Flume

Tags: hadoop, twitter4j, flume

```
{"errors":[{"message":"The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1.       https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.","code":64}]}
Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=d35baff5 or
http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=0877c84f
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[d35baff5-0877c84f], statusCode=410, retryAfter=-1,    rateLimitStatus=null, featureSpecificRateLimitStatus=null, version=2.2.6}
at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:185)
at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:65)
at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.get(HttpClientWrapper.java:85)
at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.get(TwitterImpl.java:1728)
at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.search(TwitterImpl.java:98)
at org.twitter.search.Source.SearchSource.start(SearchSource.java:85)
at org.apache.flume.source.EventDrivenSourceRunner.start(EventDrivenSourceRunner.java:44)
at org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor$MonitorRunnable.run(LifecycleSupervisor.java:251)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Failed to search tweets: 410:
```

This is the error that I am getting when I try to use Twitter's REST API with flume. I created my source file which is similar to the source file that Cloudera created (https://github.com/cloudera/cdh-twitter-example/blob/master/flume-sources/src/main/java/com/cloudera/flume/source/TwitterSource.java). Cloudera uses Streaming API while I am trying to use the Search API. I'm using Twitter4j library and called the "Search" method but for some reason it's giving me this error. I don't know what the problem it.

Comment: Are use using latest version of twitter4j jar file?

Comment: @RamananR I tested the search method from the library in Eclipse and it works. But when I try to use it to get data into HDFS, it gives me this error. I'm not sure why.

Comment: The twitter4j jar file you mention in FLUME_CLASSPATH must be old one